# "Docker is not installed or not running" error holds me back from using EPI2ME labs

Tags: docker

I installed EPI2ME Labs for Windows as described on the website of Oxford Nanopore Technologies, even with the additional installation of WSL, JAVA, nextflow, and Docker as asked during the setup. However, the next error keeps postulating "Docker is unavailable. Details: Docker is not installed or not running."

Docker was at first unable to fully install as I kept getting the error "Docker Desktop is unable to detect a Hypervisor. Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See [https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization"](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization%22). I fixed this by Installing Hyper-V in Windows 10 Home (website https://www.itechtics.com/enable-hyper-v-windows-10-home/?fbclid=IwAR0glhu2lDISgP6HbhedAxYcqIXY_tI6UcDu7HyWNVtOlUHWz1RNMovIHDM). This enabled me to get Docker running without the previous error. However, this did not fix the error in the EPI2ME Lab app. Does anyone know how I can fix this error in EPI2ME lab so I can run my workflows?

Comment: You need to enable Hyper-V in Windows features and Virtualization in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

When running the command `docker container list` I obtained the following output:

> The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro. We recommend to convert this distro to WSL 2 and activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings. For details about using Docker Desktop with WSL 2, visit: docs.docker.com/go/wsl2

In addition, I ran the next command `wsl.exe -l -v` to see what version of WSL is running and obtained the following output:

```
NAME STATE VERSION
* Ubuntu Running 1
docker-desktop-data Running 2
docker-desktop Running 2
```

I did this prior and after `wsl.exe --set-default-version 2` but nothing seems to change.

However, I followed the instructions on the website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers to change from WSL1 to WSL2 by running `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2`.

EPI2ME Labs is now up and running without the error described before.

Comment: Can you please include how exactly you changed from WSL1 to WSL2? I assume you ran `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2`?

Comment: Exactly, I ran the command [wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2] in Windows PowerShell